# Help with question from Bishop's "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" - 2.43

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, normal-distribution

I've been having difficulties with the following question:

[image]

I feel this is a very simple problem that I'm overthinking, but I've been stumped on this question for a while. I've tried to simplify it and turn the integral into the gamma function, but I can't figure out how to do it! x is only present in the exp() function, so I can't understand how to transform it into something else. I would appreciate any help directing me to the right way to do this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use $\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty x^{t-1} e^{-x} \,\mathrm d x$, right? Well, not only is there not an $x^{t-1}$, the exponent has that annoying $q$ in it. Try getting rid of that problem first and then worry about the other one.

More explicit hint, click to reveal:

> Use a change of variables to $u = \frac{\lvert x \rvert^q}{2 \sigma^2}$. Careful with the limits of integration when you do.